# Why the behaviour of string differs here? Why the first for loop print nothing and second print the output correctly

Tags: c++, c++11

In this `String` length encoding algorithm I am not able to understand the strange behaviour of the string. Can anyone explain on the usage of strings? The first `for loop` below prints nothing while the second prints correctly. I tried to use size, length and resize, still the first `for loop` prints nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str, newstr;
    str="aabcccccaaa";
    newstr[0]=str[0];
    cout<<str;
    int j = 1;
    for (int i =0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
            int count =1;
            while(i+1 != str.length() && str[i] == str[i+1])
            {
                count++; i++;
            }
            newstr[j] = '0'+count;
            if(i+1 != str.length())
            {   newstr[j+1] = str[i+1];
                j=j+1;
            }
            j=j+1;
    }
    cout<<"\nRun String:";
    for(int i =0; i<newstr.size(); i++) // First For loop.
        cout<<newstr[i];
    for(int i=0; i<j; i++) // Second For loop.
        cout<<newstr[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newstr` is an empty string. When you do this

```
newstr[0]=str[0];
```

or this

```
newstr[j] = '0'+count;
```

or this

```
newstr[j+1] = str[i+1];
```

you invoke *undefined behaviour* by accessing its storage out of bounds. All bets are off after that. First, fix those errors.

Comment: ideally he would be using `push_back` or something instead of using `[]`, but adding a `newstr.resize(str.size());` made his program run successfully.